# When log into standard account of PC run VBS that requires admin privs

Tags: windows, vbscript

I need when I log into Windows account of standard user, VBS file should be run automatically.

I know I can create a new string value in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` with data like

```
wscript.exe D:\my-script.vbs
```

But the operation that should be run in VBS file when I log into user account requires admin privs

How to resolve the task?

Comment: You should login with an administrative account, create a scheduled task, add a trigger that waits for a logon event. Depending in your needs add stored credentials to it.

Answer (score 0):

The above should work. And remember to add ADMINISTRATOR credentials for the task.
Your first step is to find a "Task scheduler".